# ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Al querer crear un super usuario

Tags: python, django

Estaba intentando usar el comando winpty python manage.py createsuperuser pero al usarlo me sale el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available o
n your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual env
ironment?
```

Comment: seria mejor que instales Django devuelta, debió ver un error en ese momento creo, no es normal que pase eso

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que no este activado tu entorno virtual y no tengas instalado Django fuera del entorno y por eso da ese error o que no se haya instalado Django en tu entorno.

Primero asegúrate que tengas Django instalado de manera global o en tu entorno virtual mediante:

```
pip list
```

Debería de aparecer Django en la lista de paquetes, si no te aparece es que no esta instalado.

Si estas usando un entorno virtual donde ya instalaste Django es probable que no este activado por eso te da ese error al intentar ejecutar manage.py createsuperuser. Primero activa tu entorno donde tengas instalado Django y entonces ya ejecuta el comando y no debería de haber problema.